# onOpen running outside of the sheet being opened

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Using Apps Script, I have an email compiler tool built where you select a record, then hit "send email" from a custom ui. It then pulls a popup with a text field for you to enter the email recipient. But that address prompt comes up on opening the sheet on it's own.

Also any additional functions I try to run from the editor are causing that address prompt to pop up. My onOpen is pretty simple:

```
function onOpen() {
 
 let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
    ui.createMenu('Email Tools')
      .addItem('Compile Email','emailSend')
      .addToUi();

}
```

The only thing I can think of is in the emailSend function, it calls the onOpen() as well. If it doesn't, the UI for the "Email Tools" doesn't load. Now I'm at a loss for how to untangle this.

```
onOpen();
var emailTo = addressPrompts();
function emailSend(emailTo) {
  let toField = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('to');
  let ccField = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('cc');
```

I've tried modifying the trigger for the `addressPrompt()` function because it is currently set up to run `onOpen`. That didn't seem to help.

If I disable the `onOpen()` from the `emailSend` function, then the menu doesn't load to the spreadsheet at all.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow! Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the line:

```
onOpen();
```

within your script. The `onOpen();` calls the `ui` function and causes you the problem.

Google Apps Script only needs the definition of the function `function onOpen() {...}`.

Comment: The issue is that if I remove that, then the popup comes up, but my ui Menu doesn't.

I was eventually able to figure it out. Turns out because I had my popup as a separate function, it was passing the `onOpen();` through the UI. 

Issue is now resolved.